# CMake include_directories skips OS X frameworks

Tags: macos, cmake

I'm using CMake 3.3.2 on OS X Yosemite. If I put a framework path into `include_directories` the generated Makefile doesn't include that directory. A short example:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(testproj)
include_directories(/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework)
add_library(testlib test.c)
```

The make output:

```
Scanning dependencies of target testlib
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/testlib.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/testlib.dir/build
[ 50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/testlib.dir/test.c.o
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc    -o CMakeFiles/testlib.dir/test.c.o   -c /Users/wrar/test/test.c
```

I expected the `include_directories` command to have an effect on the compiler line, and as the official `OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR` has the value I passed in the example, I expect it to be a correct value. What am I missing?

Comment: `include_directories` should come **before** add_library for take effect on the library.

Comment: @Tsyvarev doesn't make any difference, I've updated the example

Comment: Does `target_include_directories` work for you?

Comment: To filter out OSX framework paths is part of CMake's implementation: see [ENH: make sure default /System framework is not added with -F](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/commit/5ed2141d12c6be54902cb26a83d2b97fba8699cb) commit. I think the reasoning behind it is that your CMake project should not depend on the OSX version/installation you are using.

Comment: @Florian well, that's what `FindOpenGL` gave me

Comment: @wRAR I agree that this is confusing, but - since it's an integral part of CMake for OSX - I don't think you can easily change this. You could e.g. add a `message(STATUS "OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR: ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR}")` to document where `OpenGL` was found. And - if you don't want the framework to be first - you may want to look at `CMAKE_FIND_FRAMEWORK` global variable, which takes `FIRST`, `LAST` and `NEVER`. For some additional information on the topic see [here](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2005-December/007740.html) and [here](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:HowToUseExistingOSXFrameworks).

Comment: @usr1234567 no difference

Comment: @Florian I admit I'm missing something important. I've used `find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)` and then `include_directories(${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR})` and this doesn't work on OS X while working on Linux and looking correct according to docs. Do I need additional commands to make it work on OS X or where is the problem?

Comment: @wRAR The theory is that you don't need those framework include paths because they are implicit. Could you please add the error messages you get? I suppose "include not found", but the details may be interesting.

Comment: @Florian looks like the problem is this: the software ships `glext.h` which should be included before the system one.

Comment: @wRAR See also [cmake not finding gl.h on OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26745284/cmake-not-finding-gl-h-on-os-x). I've just tested it and if I do `#include <OpenGL/glext.h>` the header in the framework is found. But if I understand correctly, you have two versions of `glext.h` and you want the version in `/some/other/path` to be preferred. So if I give `include_directories(SYSTEM /some/other/path)` I get `cc -isystem /some/other/path -o CMakeFiles/testlib.dir/test.c.o -c /Users/Shared/Projects/IncludesOpenGL/test.c`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Turning my comments into an answer*

**Standard framework include paths are filtered by CMake**

CMake has a lot of special handling for OS X Frameworks. One of it is to remove explicitly named framework include and library search paths (see this [commit](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/commit/5ed2141d12c6be54902cb26a83d2b97fba8699cb)).

I agree that it's confusing that

```
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR: ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR}")
include_directories(${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR})
add_library(...)
```

does return `OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework` but you don't find this path in the `cc` command line.

But this search path is implicit, meaning the compiler knows best where to find the framework's header files. So this filtering of the OS X framework include/library directories in CMake does reflect the special handling of the compiler/linker when working with frameworks.

**How does the compiler find a framework's include file?**

By the framework's name given as an include's directory name. See [MAC Developer Library/Framework Programming Guide/Including Frameworks](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/IncludingFrameworks.html):

> You include framework header files in your code using the #include directive. [...]
>
> ```
>   #include <Framework_name/Header_filename.h>
> ```

See [cmake not finding gl.h on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26745284/cmake-not-finding-gl-h-on-os-x) for more details.

I've just tested your example and added e.g. `#include <OpenGL/glext.h>` to `test.c` and the header in the framework is found.

If you don't want the OpenGL standard framework to be found first (the default), see [`find_path` documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/find_path.html) and look for `CMAKE_FIND_FRAMEWORK`.

Or if you have your own OpenGL distribution in `/some/other/path` - and you omit the use of `find_package(OpenGL)` - you can give `include_directories(SYSTEM /some/other/path)`.

Comment: Passing the local dir via `-isystem` doesn't help the compiler to use the local header first (the code includes `<OpenGL/glu.h>` before `"glext.h"`), do I need to change the code?

Comment: @wRAR You could add `add_compile_options("$<$<PLATFORM_ID:Darwin>:-include/some/other/path/glext.h>")` before your `add_library()` call. That would [enforce the include](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387453/include-header-files-using-command-line-option) to be first in all files you compile in your project on OS X. Or you use the same with [`target_compile_options()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/target_compile_options.html) to be more specific.